# Help me evaluate $\int \arccos(\frac{x^3-3x}{2})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve $\int \arccos(\frac{x^3-3x}{2})dx$. I tried integration by parts by adding an $x'$, but it didn't work. I also tried a change of variable with $\cos(t) = \frac{x^3-3x}{2}$, but that didn't get anywhere either. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you know the integral of $\arccos x$?

Comment: integration by parts should work see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28arccos%28%28x%5E3-3*x%29/2%29,x%29)

Comment: I can integrate that easily by parts: $\int arccosx dx = xarccosx - \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = xarccosx - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac {2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = xarccosx - \frac{1}{2} \int (1-x^2)'(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx = xarccosx - \frac {1}{2} 2 \sqrt{1-x^2} + C = xarccosx - \sqrt{1-x^2} + C $. But I don't see how it helps me

Comment: Once again: "solve" is the wrong word here.  One _solves_ problems and one _solves_ equations.  One _evaluates_ expressions.  In particular, one _evaluates_ integrals.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, you are right. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

integrate by parts: Let $f=\arccos\left(\frac{x^3 - 3x}{2}\right)$, $g'=1$. Then $g=x$ and $$f'= -\frac{3(x^2-1)}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}(x^3-3x)^2}}.$$ Thus 
$$\begin{align*}
\int fg'~dx & = x\arccos\left(\frac{x^3 - 3x}{2}\right)  + \int\frac{3x^3-3x}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}(x^3-3x)^2}}~dx \\
&= x\arccos\left(\frac{x^3 - 3x}{2}\right) + \int\frac{3x(x^2-1)}{\sqrt{4-(x^3-3x)^2}}~dx \\

\end{align*}$$

At this point you note that $$4-(x^3-3x)^2 = -(x^2-1)^2(x^2-4).$$

Can you take if from here?

Comment: well I _did_ get to this point, but couldn't get further than this. The $\int \arccos x dx$ case worked because I could supply a $(1-x^2)'$ in the numerator; this one can't be tackled that way

Comment: It is worth it to notice that $$1 - \frac{1}{4} (x^3 - 3 x)^2 = \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{4} \right) (1 - x^2)^2.$$

Comment: @sos440 this is __exactly__ the hint I needed. Thank you! I'd accept this if you wrote it as an answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

$x \arccos \left(\frac{x^3-3x}{2}\right)-3 \sqrt{4-x^2 }$

Comment: Not a very enlightening answer, no?